# The Elasticsearch client version [7] is not compatible with the Elasticsearch cluster version [8.8.2]

Tags: elasticsearch, fscrawler, elasticsearch-8

I have upgraded Elasticsearch from 7.17.11 to 8.8.2.

```
# curl localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "test.example.com",
  "cluster_name" : "es_master01",
  "cluster_uuid" : "U4n0aCHtTdinDZSH5jEcdg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.8.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "98e1271edf932a480e4262a471281f1ee295ce6b",
    "build_date" : "2023-06-26T05:16:16.196344851Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I am using fscrawler version "fscrawler-es7-2.9"

To index the PDF along with its external meta tags using above Fscrawler version, I have written the following command:

```
# curl -s -v -w "\n%{http_code}" -X POST -F "file=@test.pdf" -F "tags=@test.txt" http://localhost:8080/fscrawler/_upload -k
```

Fscrawler REST interface is running on port 8080 (the default port).

I get the following error:

```
07:52:48,282 FATAL [f.p.e.c.f.c.FsCrawlerCli] We can not start Elasticsearch Client. Exiting.
java.lang.RuntimeException: The Elasticsearch client version [7] is not compatible with the Elasticsearch cluster version [8.8.2].
```

Does this mean that Fscrawler v2.9 is not compatible with Elasticsearch v8.8.2?  Or am I missing something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Fscrawler 2.10-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Okay, thanks, Is there any tentative release date of Fscrawler 2.10-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Nope. But this is by far the most stable version.